# Clear or selectively delete Remote Desktop Connection history

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Remote Desktop Connection on Windows (mstsc) saves the previous computers you have connected to in the "Computer" dropdown.

How can I clear them, or selectively delete entries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you navigate to the following location in the registry, you should be able to see a list of connections made;

"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default"

Under this key you should be able to remove any entries.

see [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312169)

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me that, after clearing the list under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default`, there still was one computer listed. I found out that, in my Documents folder, there was a `Default.rdp` **hidden** file. Deleting that file, or simply removing the line containing the computer name in the file (which can be opened with a regular text editor) did the trick.